# get horizental line from lowest point to crop

Tags: python, opencv

I am try to remove extra spacing in drawing using opencv. My goal is to remove extra parts from the closed drawing.

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np
name = '006.png'
img=cv2.imread(name)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = 255 - gray
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
kernel = np.ones((75,75), np.uint8)
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
#cv2.imwrite('mask.png',mask)
```

[image: input image],my current mask is getting exactly the the black boxes which will help me in cropping the image.

[image: mask image], I want to crop the image 4 times (top,both sides, bottom) by making a horizental line of the lowest point of that side accordingly. My expected Output is [image: output image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do that in Python/OpenCV.

- Read the input
- Convert to grayscale
- Threshold
- Apply morphology open to remove the thin outer lines then morphology close to connect the left and right halves
- Find the largest contour
- Get contour bounding box
- Crop image
- Draw contour on input image
- Save results

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread('006.png')
hh, ww = img.shape[:2]

# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# invert gray image
gray = 255 - gray

# threshold
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# apply close and open morphology
kernel = np.ones((3,3), np.uint8)
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# get largest contour
contours = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
big_contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(big_contour)

# draw contour on input
contour_img = img.copy()
cv2.drawContours(contour_img,[big_contour],0,(0,0,255),3)

# crop to bounding rectangle
crop = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]

# save cropped image
cv2.imwrite('006_thresh.png',thresh)
cv2.imwrite('006_mask.png',mask)
cv2.imwrite('006_contour.png',contour_img)
cv2.imwrite('006_cropped.png',crop)

# show the images
cv2.imshow("THRESH", thresh)
cv2.imshow("MASK", mask)
cv2.imshow("CONTOUR", contour_img)
cv2.imshow("CROP", crop)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Thresholded image:

[image]

Morphology cleaned mask image:

[image]

Contour on input image:

[image]

Cropped image:

[image]